# Why the trigger 'when any file is created in a folder' lunch the robot 2 times ? (AutomationAnywhere 11.1)

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have just a message box that show the $Trigger Value$ in my robot.
When i put the trigger 'When a file is created' of the type 'folder' it shows me the name of the file 2 times.
How can i make it appears only one time ?

This is what I see:

[image: This is what I see]

This is the trigger I set up:

[image: This is the trigger I set up]

This is my message box:

[image: This is my message box]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not putting the $Trigger Value$ in the message box twice?

After testing, this is the only way I could get it to incorrectly populate twice like you describe:
[image: Incorrect Message Box]

Also, make sure you don't have duplicate triggers setup in the AAE Trigger Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the task runs two times? If yes, make sure that you created only one trigger for the task, in the triggers manager.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h7QL.png)

Comment: Yes the task runs two times and I have only one trigger for this task. 
But this issue not only appears on this task, every task that have this trigger runs two times when it's triggered

Comment: - End AutomationEventWatcher.exe from the Task Manager
- Restart the Automation Anywhere services,

Answer (score 0):

So I find where the error comes from :

When I disable the trigger from an other task, the task 'test' only runs one time. 
I don't really understand why because this trigger doesn't look at the same folder and the 'watch subfolder' is not checked and it should trigger the other task.

Can someone explain me this ?